# HTML Editor not working in publishing pages - SharePoint

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, publishing-page

I am developing a SharePoint publishing portal wherein I make use of HTML Editor(third party control) in my page layout for editing the contents.

When I try to edit the page using the publishing console, the HTML Editor which I have added in my page doesn't appear at all. I monitored the design at run time using firebug and it showed no content. Where could I be wrong?

Regards,Sankaran D

Comment: Please add more details. What third party HTML Editor, how is this being used / integrated?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a wild guess and say you are trying to use the Telerik RadEditor to replace the hopeless SharePoint 2007 OOB rich text editor control. The control is not being rendered, so Firebug will not help you.

Have you followed all the steps to install the editor? You will need to refer to the instructions the developer gives, probably adding and deploying a solution package and activating a feature. In the case of the Telerik control there is an option to replace all your existing rich text controls with the RadEditor. You might want to try that approach.